# Increase connection Timeout connect to server

Tags: networking, ssh

When i use terminal to ssh to machine A: it takes some 10 seconds and then prompts for password

I am using connect to server options to use `sftp` to connect to machine A and it says : timed-out while logging in.

Does anyone know how to increase the connection timeout while using connect to server option in ubuntu 15.04?

**EDIT :**
This is the GUI I am talking about, the connect to server option can be seen below *Browse Network*
[image]

Changing the options in */etc/ssh/ssh_config* didn't work

**EDIT 2:**

I just upgraded my system to Ubuntu 15.10 and voila, it started working!
I don't know how, but I am glad it works now, is there a way I can withdraw the bounty?

Comment: Could you ever connect via SFTP?

Comment: yeah i have tried connecting via sftp using the terminal and that works! It's the gui that's creating problems!

Comment: when you changed the options for timeout in /etc/ssh/sshd_config  did you then allso do `sudo service ssh restart`? I see you said /etc/ssh/config is that really waht you meant?

Comment: sorry, i meant /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: yeah i did restart, infact i restarted the system too, still no luck!

Comment: @VikashB, unfortunately "You may not cancel a bounty once it has been started." see https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty

Comment: If you solved the issue, add and accept an answer explaining it so people don't come and read your problems...

Comment: No, i haven't solved the issue, it just went away after i upgraded to 15.10

Comment: Yes, please write a short answer and set it as solution, so it won't show up as open question.  It might have been a bug, fixed by a newer version. But there's no way to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as suggested:

This issue has been resolved in both 15.10 and 16.04, so if you guys are up for it, do a dist upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal place to put this is in your `~/.ssh/config` file.  Putting these options in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` will make the change for all users on the system which is often undesirable.  Additionally, these changes will not be portable were you to move your home directory for another server.  Within your `config` file one can make a change as follows:

```
Host example-server
    HostName server.example.com
    Port 2200
    User example-user
    ConnectionTimeout 20
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Performing the changes in this way also allows you to make additional configuration changes which would not be available in the GUI interface (such as port number, or changing GSS API support).

From there in the "connect to server" interface, simply reference the name "`example-server`" rather than the fully qualified domain name (`FQDN`) to use these options.